# Microsoft.Maui.IPropertyMapper - The type '' cannot be used as a type parameter... There is no implicit conversion

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I'm trying to get maps to work on .net MAUI and found this blog post (linked to from the official MAUI blog). https://www.cayas.de/blog/dotnet-maui-custom-map-handler
I've downloaded the repo linked at the end of the blog but I can't get it to run.

In the blog post the MapHandler code looks like this:

```
public static IPropertyMapper<IMap, MapHandler> MapMapper = new PropertyMapper<IMap, MapHandler>(ViewMapper)
    {  };
```

But in the repo it looks like this:

```
public static IPropertyMapper<MapView, MapHandler> MapMapper = new PropertyMapper<MapView, MapHandler>(ViewMapper)
        { };
```

Neither of which work for me, as I get the error (at runtime) below.

```
The type 'MapControlDemo.Handlers.MapHandler' cannot be used as type parameter 'TViewHandler' in the generic type or method 'PropertyMapper<TVirtualView, TViewHandler>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'MapControlDemo.Handlers.MapHandler' to 'Microsoft.Maui.IElementHandler'
```

Confusingly there are another couple of errors that shouldn't be errors??
[image: Other errors]

Any ideas? I contacted the author and he suggested it could be my maui version as it works for him, but I'm on the latest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the author was building on a Mac.

I've confirmed that an attempt to build on Windows results in a build error. VS Version 17.3.0 Preview 1.1
The error I got was

```
Error   CS0311  The type 'MapControlDemo.Handlers.MapHandler' cannot be used
 as type parameter 'TViewHandler'
 in the generic type or method 'IPropertyMapper<TVirtualView, TViewHandler>'.
 There is no implicit reference conversion from
 'MapControlDemo.Handlers.MapHandler' to
 'Microsoft.Maui.IElementHandler'.
    MapControlDemo (net6.0-android) C:\...\maui-maps\Handlers\MapHandler.cs 6
```

HOWEVER, I was able to RUN on Android - by selected an Android emulator as target (so using `net6.0-android`) and pressing F5 - therefore that error is misleading.

---

Given that this is only implemented on iOS and Android, I recommend editing `.csproj` to REMOVE `Windows` platform. I also removed MacCatalyst (maybe that would work but I was going for simplest test):
Change:

```xml
        <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-android;net6.0-ios;net6.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

To:

```xml
        <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-android;net6.0-ios</TargetFrameworks>
```

Then I was able to build.

NOTE: Without adding a Google Maps ID, when ran on Android, the result was an empty map.

**tl;dr** Easiest way to test is on a Mac, targetting iOS.

Comment: Nice, works, thanks! (well actually the map isn't rendering on android for some reason, how can I debug that? On windows app I can crtl + shift + i to see developer tools) so it's because there isn't an implementation for windows?

Comment: **1)** As I mentioned, on Android you'll get an empty map. That's because you have to go to Google's website, create a Google Maps developer ID, etc. Google explains it all somewhere. **2)** Windows - correct, that code has no implementation for Windows.

Comment: Many thanks Steve, lastly, might you know how I could go about implementing the handler for windows?

Comment: Sorry, not my area of knowledge. Perhaps the article author has suggestions.

Comment: He has not. Otherwise I would have implemented it. ;-)
The empty Google Maps is because, as ToolmakerSteve mentioned, due to the missing Google Maps API key. I linked to the Google Maps guide from Microsoft in the article that should set you up quickly.